fprintf from an Edit box (Borland)
Hello and thank you in advance for any help.
I have a few hundred TEdit boxes, and I need to dump their data to a file. Easy enough if I write them all out separately like this:
fprintf(data_fptr, "%s", Form1->Edit1->Text);
fprintf(data_fptr, "%s", Form1->Edit2->Text);
fprintf(data_fptr, "%s", Form1->Edit3->Text);
etc...

But I don't want to. I stumbled my way into this fancy loop that saves a lot of code space:
edit_n is my concatenated string, and buffer is just a storage tank for a number (1-99). So the first string looks like "Form1->Edit1->Text".
data_fptr = fopen("c:\\test\\test.ini", "w+");
char edit_n[80];
char buffer[80];

int n = 1;

do {
  sprintf(buffer, "%d", n);
  strcat(edit_n, "Form1->Edit"); // first part of the string
  strcat(edit_n, buffer); // number of the Edit box
  strcat(edit_n, "->Text"); // last part of the string
  fprintf(data_fptr, "%ls\n", edit_n); // prints the string (data) to the file
  n++; // increments n
  sprintf(edit_n, ""); // clears the string for the next use
} while (n < 100);

fclose(data_fptr);

It works, but instead of writing the data contained in Edit1 to the file, it writes the concatenated string "Form1->Edit1->Text".
What am I missing, or how can I get it to work properly?
I tried the few things I know to do, I am not a professional programmer.

NOTE: If I use fprintf(data_fptr,"%ls\n", edit_n);, I get "?????????" written to the file. If I use fprintf(data_fptr,"%s\n", edit_n);, I get "Form1->Edit1->Text" written to the file.

%ls expects a wchar_t* string, but edit_n is a char[] array that decays into a char* pointer

First, you can't pass the TEdit::Text property as-is to fprintf().  The %s specifier is expecting a char* pointer to a null-terminated string. The only reason your original code even works at all is because fprintf() uses C-style variadic parameters that are not type-safe, and the Text property returns an AnsiString 1 object whose sole data member is a char* pointer to the character data, so fprintf() happens to end up receiving that pointer.  But don't rely on this internal detail.  Instead, you must use the Text.c_str() method to get a proper pointer to the character data.
1: Since you mention Borland, I'm assuming you are using a pre-Unicode version of C++Builder, where the TEdit::Text property returns an 8-bit AnsiString and its c_str() method returns a char* pointer. That would match with your use of the %s specifier in fprintf().  In 2009, the Text property was changed to a 16-bit UnicodeString, whose c_str() method returns a wchar_t* (Windows) or char16_t* (Posix) pointer.
Second, to avoid duplicating the same code over and over, you are on the correct track by wanting to use a loop, however your loop is writing the completely wrong thing to your file.  You are formatting a char[] buffer containing a string that describes a TEdit object, but you are not actually accessing that object.
You need to instead put your TEdit object pointers into an array/container and then loop over that, accessing each one's Text property, eg:
TEdit* edits[100];
...
edits[0] = Form1->Edit1;
edits[1] = Form1->Edit2;
// and so on ...

for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    fprintf(data_fptr, "%s\n", edits[n]->Text.c_str());
}

Alternatively, the TForm object does have a public FindComponent() method, eg:
for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    TEdit *edit = (TEdit*) Form1->FindComponent("Edit"+String(n));
    fprintf(data_fptr, "%s\n", edit->Text.c_str());
}

or:
TEdit* edits[100];
...
for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    edits[n] = (TEdit*) Form1->FindComponent("Edit"+String(n+1));
}
...
for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    fprintf(data_fptr, "%s\n", edits[n]->Text.c_str());
}


Thank you, your answer is brilliant!
I use Embarcadero Rad Studio 12.1 for C++ work.
I used your suggestions of:
for(int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
TEdit edit = (TEdit) Form1->FindComponent("Edit"+String(n));
fprintf(data_fptr, "%s\n", edit->Text.c_str());
}
Now, if I may bother you one more time, how do I reverse this when I need to scan the data in?

@KennethWood alternatively something with data sources can be used. Unless Embrocadero got dumbed down compared to what Borland Builder had in 2000s you can create mechanism to serialize data in a semi-visual way.

"I use Embarcadero Rad Studio 12.1" - then there is no way your original code could work. You would have to use %ls instead of %s. But since you are using C++, why are you using C file I/O functions? Why not use C++'s std::ofstream class instead? Or C++Builder's own RTL functions/classes like FileCreate()+FileWrite(), TFileStream/TStreamWriter, TFile, etc? Or, in your particular example, a simple TStringList would suffice (which has SaveToFile() and LoadFromFile() methods). If you are going to use C++Buidler's UI framework, then you should use its RTL framework, too.
